# Game theory solution for HAM radio users during apocalypse

Tags: society, technology, post-apocalypse, game-theory

### Premise

Consider the cult classic scene of a zombie apocalypse where pockets of survivors are reconnecting over radio channels. One party claims to offer salvation, drawing in small groups of survivors -- only to discover that the 'salvation' turns out to be a predatory trap to exploit survivors.

Though over-used, this plot fascinated me, and led me to map out the strategies of survivors -- at which point I attempted to use game theory.

> Broadcast: "We have food, water and shelter. We can offer you
>   salvation."
>
> Survivors: "How do I know I can trust you?"

Unlike simpler games in game theory where players' choices have little to no influence on other players choices, in my post-apocalyptic world, knowing if the broadcast was genuine or a trap would clearly prompt a strategy reset from the survivors contemplating to join the broadcasting party.

### Question

How would HAM radio users likely continue the above conversation? That is to say, what litmus tests could survivors formulate over the radio to optimize their survival strategy? Or equivalently, what red flags might clue survivors in that the broadcast may be predatory?

**Note:** Incurring some risk may be unavoidable, so practically speaking, the goal here is to vet the broadcasters as much as possible before any physical meet ups.

**Further clarifications:**

- Power grid is down
- Number of total survivors is unknown, presumed to be small
- Environmental hazards exist (some fallout)
- Resources abundance is moderate
- Threat of marauding gangs is growing

Comment: You may be interested in [Drama Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drama_theory), which is the open-ended big brother to Game Theory.  It recognizes that there's not just a single round to the game, and you may change your rules between rounds.

Comment: once you replied they can track you and they will try to keep you on the air while they triangulate on you.

Comment: @user6760 No, they won't, because for all they know, you're letting them triangulate you on purpose, planning on trapping *them*

Comment: @user6760 HFDF requires a certain investment in time, effort and infrastructure, all of which are hard to come by in a peri-apocalypse. Actively going out and hunting encampments down is even worse. If they have enough to be worth stealing, they are probably capable of being a threat, etc.

Comment: (FWIW, I liked this question, but it is probably off-topic here, alas. Something to think about, though, that's for sure)

Comment: If they have a low number of stars on Yelp and reviews like "They ate my children...AVOID" then you probably shouldn't be supporting them with your resources. Try someplace local instead.

Answer (score 5):

**Lies are usually fairly transparent, especially over time**

Most folks have a lot of experience determining the truthfulness of folks or media that they interact with regularly over more than a few days. We are taught the skills to identify liars quite young. Something just doesn't feel right, they don't answer a straight question with a straight answer, their story changes from day to day, it's too good to be true, etc.

It's HARD to keep a lie consistent and detailed over time.

Let's group Survivors into two sets:

One set of Survivors are **desperate, facing death, ready to move** to the Salvationers TODAY en masse. However, it seems unlikely this group has the time or energy available to scan the radio for the Salvationers message in the first place. Let's overlook that and assume they got lucky. Next, this desperate, unprepared group may run afoul of the Marauders and become their prey instead. Finally, this set likely has little of value -- if they reach the Salvationers, they are perhaps not worth the effort of trapping them in the first place.

Interesting corollary: Seems like the best pickings for Marauders is on the approach paths to the Salvationers, so the smart ones will be thickest there. The Marauders and Salvationers are likely to come into conflict. The Salvationers have simply drawn the folks they DON'T want into conflict around their home. Seems an unwise move; there is no honor among thieves and scoundrels.

The other set of Survivors who have the **available time and energy to use a radio** would seem to be NOT on the imminent brink of death. If true, then it seems like the Survivors have plenty of time (several days) to judge the veracity of their new radio friend and determine if they want to send a scouting party or not. Post-apocalypse travel is notoriously slow and dangerous, and must be planned, prepared, and rehearsed. For our purposes, it really doesn't matter if the scouts discover the Marauders or the Salvationer trap itself, they will return with the same "don't go" result. If scouts don't return at all, the Survivors know to not go.

**Bottom Line: The Survivors with enough resources to be worth trapping are not likely to go.**

Comment: But. An idea appears: Would the Salvationers benefit from "Buying Off" the Marauders by allowing them to pick on low-value targets while allowing high-value ones through? Salvationers and Marauders may have different enough goals for this to work.

Comment: @Andon I think this is covered by "no honor among thieves and scoundrels." I suspect that it's an invalid assumption that both sides would stick to an agreement, that they could agree upon the value of any group of prey, and that there is enough prey to go around.

Comment: +1 on the detecting liars part. Most people can evaluate trustworthiness or detect lies rather easily over the course of a longer conversation. Especially if the "smart survivors" spend a few days becoming radio friends, then it's unlikely they'd fall for a simple trap

Comment: There's plenty of scope for a third population who have dealt with their immediate short term survival but whose medium-to-long term survival is in doubt who may be tempted to visit the broadcasters. This is of course a time-limited scenario as such people will solve their own problems, or wise up, or die in due course.

Comment: @StarfishPrime I considered that. Their actions seem to be the same as the second group anyway - they still have resources and time to detect the trap -- it's not going to provide the MacGuffin Powder they are starting to run low on. I defined their radio-friend-time in days instead of months specifically to include these folks. After all, every group of survivors will be running low on *something* they view as critical.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to think of possible strategies for the possible players, I came up with these:

The marauder’s strategies range from baiting survivors into their stew pot or broadcasting messages like ‘We have cookies!’ and direction finding the survivors transmitting location and attacking.

Hungry Survivor strategies range from starve to death to meet with strangers and get food or get eaten.

Non-hungry survivors strategies range from keep mouth shut and risk attracting marauder’s by trying to grow bigger and track marauders and broadcast their movements so they’ll starve to death

Since resources are abundant, and the cost of a survivor interacting with a marauder is very high.  It seems the dominant strategy is to keep hidden, forage, and wait for the marauders to stop marauding — either they starve or unify into a new world order.

If you are a starving survivor, there is no real risk in looking for well fed survivors or well fed marauders.  Whether you die of starvation or die in a stock pot, dead is dead.  And, maybe you can join the marauders as something beside an entree.